# Class associations and multiplicity - UML 2.0 - object oriented (Basic)

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis, multiplicity

I am learning UML and I've focused on a Netflix-like project on which to practice on.

I've put together a class association diagram, but have been told that the multiplicities are incorrect. The multiplicities in red represent what I think they should be changed to.

Could someone please offer some clarity of where I have gone wrong?

Please, ask any questions that would help gain a fuller understanding of the diagram in reference to the project.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Movie Catalog` - `User`: The `0..*` multiplicity is correct. There can be an arbitrary number of users and not only a single one. That would only work if that Netflix was made for a very single person. And that would be pointless, I guess.

`Movie` - `Membership` - `Member`: This represents an association class for the user to track payments (and access, etc.). So it must be the `1`, not `0..*`. The stream is sent for that single `Membership` where it is accounted. An association class has a n-1-1-m relation.

In your model it looks like this:

[image]

And from my POV it is:

[image]

since the `Membership` is just used to control access to the movies. It is arguable whether there is only a 1-1 relation and not a (preferable) m-1 relation between `Member` and `Membership`.

Comment: I would think a movie could be streamed by more then one membership. So that would result in `0..*` at the Membership end, not `1`.

Comment: @GeertBellekens No. The stream is for that single membership where it is accounted. It's an Association Class thus a N-1-1-M relation.

Comment: I don't see any association classes in this diagram.

Comment: No seriously. Which association has an association class? I don't see any dotted lines from an association to a class.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I did not say, that it's denoted that way in the OP's diagram.